# Abstract class member inaccessible due it's protection level

Tags: c#, oop

How do I access a protected member of an abtsract class?  Assume I have classes defined as below

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    private int index ;

    protected int GetIndex
    {
        get { return index ;}
        set { index = value; }
    }
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
     ...
}

public class TestClass
{
     var data = new MyClass()
     var index = data.GetIndex;
}
```

The line

```
var index = data.GetIndex;
```

complains that  inaccessible due it's protection level. How do I access the GetIndex property of MyClass in TestClass?

-Alan-

Comment: Make it public or internal or using reflection?

Comment: this is not significant usage of protected identifier. You could make it public or internal..

Comment: Why do you expect protected members to be accessible outside of members of the class/derived classes? Very unclear what you trying to achieve.

Comment: NOTE: A property shouldn't contain the text `Get` or `Set`. If the property represents an index, then you should name as such `int Index { get; set; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is exactly what **protected** is meant to be used for.

It **protects** fields/methods from being used from **outside** of the base class or sub classes. TestClass is not derived from BaseClass or MyClass; and does you can't get to *GetIndex*. It is as simple as that.

Thus, your option space is:

1. Replace *protected* on BaseClass
2. Provide *other* means in MyClass to retrieve/set that property
3. Change TestClass to derive from BaseClass

No specific ordering in that list; but obviously, option 3 being the "worst" alternative here.

Comment: Well, if it would be a specific test class in some unit test directory ... maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int GetIndex { get; private set; }

    public BaseClass() { GetIndex = 0; }
}
```

Then you can set *GetIndex* only in BaseClass (your veriable *index* is private) or:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    private int index;

    public int GetIndex 
    { 
        get { return index; } 
        protected set { index = value; } 
    }
}
```